# How the docker swarm init --advertise-addr works?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am aware that we can initialize a swarm using

> docker swarm init

If the Node has multiple addresses then we need to add flag

> --advertise-addr

and provide the IP Address . This flag is for mentioning the IP address to other Nodes in the swarm for API Access.

In a cluster of 5 manager node . MGR1 is the leader ( In this node I ran

> docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.6.2.2

) . Now If I delete this Node , the cluster will appoint another manager as leader by RAFT .

My question is , If that manager node which is going to be elected as leader has more than one IP address . Then how a single IP is set like the way --advertise-addr is used at first to initialize the cluster. ?

Answer (score 2):

The advertise address is local to a node, it's not a global cluster setting. That ip is the one displayed when you get a client join command from the server, because clients need an address to connect to. You should pick an address that any node in the cluster can reach.

Comment: Thanks . What about --listen-addr ? and as you mentioned , the join tokens did have that ip . But when we are using those join tokens , do we need to replace the --advertise-addr and --listen-addr to the worker node's ip , instead of the manager node's ip ?

Comment: @bkr The join command is run on the worker/new manager. The IP address is the manager that new worker/manager needs to connect to. So you would not change that IP. You won't see the `--advertise-addr` included in the manager generated join command because it does not know anything about the client where you run the command.

Comment: Thanks BMitch . In the book , Deep dive in Docker by Nigel poulton .For adding New node's to cluster . It's mentioned to add --advertise-addr and --listen-addr flags to the join token command and give that new node's ip address .

Comment: @bkr you can add the flag and ip if needed to the join command. My comment above was in response to "replace" the ip.